# Added key, but dget still shows "gpg: Can't check signature: public key not found"

Tags: gnupg, source-packages

Trying to download Django source package using `dget` and the `.dsc` file from [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/quantal/+source/python-django).

Then dget fails to verify the source, because it is missing a public key.

```
$ dget https://launchpad.net/ubuntu...
[...]
dscverify: python-django_1.4.1-2.dsc failed signature check:
gpg: Signature made Tue 21 Aug 2012 09:12:04 CEST using RSA key ID F2AC729A
gpg: Can't check signature: public key not found
Validation FAILED!!
```

Fine, I added this key to my keyring, because I think I can trust this one:

```
$ gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-key 0xF2AC729A
gpg: requesting key F2AC729A from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: key F2AC729A: "Raphaël Hertzog <raphael@ouaza.com>" not changed
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:              unchanged: 1
```

<sup>(well, this output is run afterwards, when it was already in my keyring)</sup>

And it is really there:

```
$ gpg --fingerprint F2AC729A
pub   4096R/F2AC729A 2009-05-07
      Key fingerprint = 3E4F B711 7877 F589 DBCF  06D6 E619 045D F2AC 729A
uid                  Raphaël Hertzog <raphael@ouaza.com>
uid                  Raphaël Hertzog (Debian) <hertzog@debian.org>
uid                  Raphaël Hertzog (Freexian SARL) <raphael@freexian.com>
sub   2048R/71F23DEE 2009-05-07
```

But still fails for the same reason:

```
gpg: Signature made Tue 21 Aug 2012 09:12:04 CEST using RSA key ID F2AC729A
gpg: Can't check signature: public key not found
```

I'm running all these commands as my regular user. I also tried adding this key to APT's keyring and root's keyring. Both to no avail.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I got the same problem as you and after checking the man page of `dscverify` I found a solution:

Add following line to your `~/.devscripts`:

```
DSCVERIFY_KEYRINGS="/etc/apt/trusted.gpg:~/.gnupg/pubring.gpg"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can reverse files and use /etc/devscripts.conf:

```
DSCVERIFY_KEYRINGS="~/.gnupg/pubring.gpg:/etc/apt/trusted.gpg"
```