# Installing gawk 4.0 on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, software-installation

How do I install gawk  4.0.1 or later on ubuntu 12.04?

Your suggestions would be appreciated!!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First of all, note the information in the following question:

- [Why can't I update applications without upgrading the whole OS?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/95336/why-cant-i-update-applications-without-upgrading-the-whole-os)

This is an approach to build the Quantal (12.10) 4.0.1 version of gawk on 12.04 *as a package*. It applies to almost all packages you want to backport from a newer Ubuntu release to the one you're using. Most of the times it just builds cleanly. This one does.

1. Install some basic package build tools:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install devscripts build-essential
   sudo apt-get build-dep gawk
   ```
2. Install the key of the developer (*example key!*):

   ```
   gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-key B6897E7B
   ```

   This key identifier should be replaced by the error output of the `dget` command below.
3. Make the devscripts use your keyring too, as per [Added key, but dget still shows “gpg: Can't check signature: public key not found"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/195489/added-key-but-dget-still-shows-gpg-cant-check-signature-public-key-not-foun):

   ```
   echo 'DSCVERIFY_KEYRINGS="/etc/apt/trusted.gpg:~/.gnupg/pubring.gpg"' >> ~/.devscripts
   ```
4. Download the source package (`.dsc` file link from [`gawk` package page](http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/gawk) in the sidebar):

   ```
   dget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gawk/gawk_4.0.1+dfsg-2.dsc
   ```
5. `cd` into it:

   ```
   cd gawk-4.0.1+dfsg/
   ```
6. First attempt to build (fails possibly):

   ```
   debuild -uc -us
   ```

   if fails, relevant output with `dpkg-checkbuilddeps: Unmet build dependencies` (below is an example!):

   ```
   Unmet build dependencies: bison libreadline-dev libsigsegv-dev
   ```
7. Install the additional build dependencies you still need at this point. Example:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install bison libreadline-dev libsigsegv-dev
   ```
8. Retry building (should build fine now!):

   ```
   debuild -uc -us
   ```
9. `cd` back into the upper directory:

   ```
   cd ..
   ```
10. Find your package there:

    ```
    ls -al *.deb
    ```
11. Install it:

    ```
    sudo dpkg -i gawk_4.0.1+dfsg-2_amd64.deb
    ```
12. Enjoy!

---

In case you don't want to bother compiling this stuff, you still have two options:

#### PPA

I've uploaded this on my PPA (waiting to be built at this moment) for your convenience.

- [My PPA](https://launchpad.net/~gertvdijk/+archive/various)
- [What are PPAs and how do I use them?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them)

#### Manual installation of Quantal binary package

1. Download the appropriate `.deb` file from the `packages.ubuntu.com` [page](http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/gawk), e.g. [`http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gawk/gawk_4.0.1+dfsg-2_amd64.deb`](http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gawk/gawk_4.0.1+dfsg-2_amd64.deb)
2. Install it manually:

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i gawk_4.0.1+dfsg-2_amd64.deb
   ```

Answer (score 0):

gertvdiijk's answer is probably right but I couldn't figure out what to do.
I found:

https://launchpad.net/~schot/+archive/ubuntu/gawk

has a PPA for Gnu Awk 4.0:

To get it from there you might want to execute:

```
apt-get install python-software-properties
add-apt-repository ppa:schot/gawk
apt-get update
apt-get install gawk
```

The link [What are PPAs and how do I use them?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them) was not directly helpful for me because it was only a link and did not have detailed instructions on what to really do given Ubuntu 12.04 LTS - I had to do a few trial and error attempts before I got to the four lines above.